# Event before sending Ajax Request (to add some data to the request)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I added a CSRF Token to my application. Normal forms are working fine, but now I have to adjust all ajax-requests too.

There are a lot of ajax-requests in different places, thats why I am looking for a simple way to fix this problem.

Is there some kind of event, that is triggered before sending an ajax-request, so I can add my CSRF Token to the request?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/

Comment: You may need to read this [article](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ajax-and-forms/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [.ajaxSend()](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/)

You can use ajaxSend for this, it allows you to change the url before you do the ajax request.

```
$( document ).ajaxSend(function( event, jqxhr, settings ) {
  if ( settings.url == "ajax/test.html" ) {
    $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxSend handler." );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to methods mentioned in the article listed in comments there is also 
`beforeSend(..)` function that is called before AJAX request is send.
See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind event listener for different AJAX event [see here](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/)

```
 $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
   $("#loading").show();
 }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
   $("#loading").hide();
 });
```

In the sameway you can bind your method as

```
$(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
  // code to add CSRF token
 })
```

These events are triggered on the document and are **GLOBAL EVENT**.